# How to check if an element of a list contains some substring

Tags: python, string, list, find

The below code does not work as intended and looks like optimising to search in the complete list instead of each element separately and always returning true.

Intended code is to search the substring in each element of the list only in each iteration and return true or false. But it's actually looking into complete list.

In the below code the print statement is printing complete list inside `<<>>` if I use find() or in operator but prints only one word if I use == operator.

The issue code:

```
def myfunc(mylist):
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        count = 0
        for word in mylist:
            print('<<{}>>'.format(word))
            if str(word).casefold().find('abc') or 'def' in str(word).casefold():
                count += 1
                abcdefwordlist.append(str(word)) 
                break
```

This code search for 'abc' or 'def' in mylist insted of the word.

If I use `str(word).casefold() == 'abc' or str(word).casefold() == 'def'` then it compares with word only.
How can I check word contains either of 'abc' or 'def' in such a loop.

Comment: running your code on a costume list prints the first word inside the `<< >>` and then raises ` `NameError` on `abcdefwordlist`...

Comment: What does `mylist` look like? is `word` already a string?

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you're doing anything with `i`, so what is the outer loop supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems here.

1. `abcdefwordlist` is not defined (at least not in the code you showed us).
2. You're looping over the length of the list and then over the list of word itself, which means that too many elements will be added to your resulting array.
3. This function doesn't return anything, unless you meant for it to just update `abcdefwordlist` from outside of it.

You had the right idea with `'def' in str(word)` but you have to use it in for both substrings. To sum up, a function that does what you want would look like this:

```
def myfunc(mylist):
    abcdefwordlist = [] # unless it already exists elsewhere
    for word in mylist:
        if 'abc' in str(word).lower() or 'def' in str(word).lower():
            abcdefwordlist.append(word)
    return abcdefwordlist
```

This can also be sortened to a one-liner using list comprehension:

```
def myfunc(mylist):
    return [word for word in mylist if 'abc' in str(word).lower() or 'def' in str(word).lower()]
```

BTW I used `lower()` instead of `casefold()` because the substrings I'm searching for are definetly lowercase